# How to set a specific date (fixed value) as default value on a date field?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I have a commerce order on which I have added a date field. The options for the default value are **Now** or **Relative**. How can I add a fixed default value, f.x. **20 Aug 2016**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it isn't clarify about if the datefield is asking you for a PHP code or not; you can just use this:

```
2016-08-20
```

In that way the field will change that date into what you want.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Where to add it? In a form alter function? I am using the administration interface to add the field and set its default value.

Comment: You said you had 2 values, now or relative, you need to put this line of code inside the relative part

Comment: I get an error message: _The Strtotime default value is invalid._

Comment: Place this : 2016-08-20, that should work and tell me what does it print

Comment: No, it doesn't work... But **now** or **relative** don't work either. I display the date field on the commerce checkout form. Maybe there the default values are somehow reset. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: I will alter the checkout form and add there the default values.

Comment: I tested the default value `2016-08-20` on a date field, in an article content type and it works. It seems that there is a bug on commerce checkout form, where the default values for date fields are unset.

Comment: Ok, good luck with that

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect the suggestion from your comment?

Comment: Ok, just did it